# How to create your custom XmlAttribute Serialization

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I'm looking on who to customize the serialization of an attribute. I thought it would be simple, but I was not able to achieve what I wanted to do the way I wanted.

So here is a simple example:

Class Definition:

```
Class MyClass
{
    [XmlAttribute("myAttribute")]
    public int[] MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Xml Result that I would like:

```
<MyClass myAttribute="1 2 3... N" />
```

The only work around I did to have that was to put a [XmlIgnore] attribute and create another property with some code that did the transformation.

So, my question, is there a better way than creating a new property? Maybe there is some kind of TypeConverter you can create so the serializer would use it?

Also, I've tried to use the Type attribute but without success. (Always getting exceptions). But from what I've read, it's for already defined datatype.

```
[XmlAttribute("myAttribute", typeof(MyConverter))]
public int[] MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Another interesting way would be like that:

```
[XmlAttribute("myAttribute")]
[XmlConverter(typeof(MyConverter))]
public int[] MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Thanks.

---

Edit
Since no solution like I was looking for was presented, I finally decided to opt for the "IXmlSerializable" solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either:

1. Implement `IXmlSerializable` and
   handle all the
   serialization/deserialization for
   your type manually
2. Use a surrogate property:

   ```
   [XmlIgnore]
   public int[] MyProperty { get; set; }


   [XmlAttribute("myAttribute")]
   public string _MyProperty
   {
       get
       {
           return string.Join(" ", MyProperty.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
       }
       set
       {
           MyProperty = value.Split(' ').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Your surrogate property is exactly what he's trying to avoid.

Comment: You just need to add spaces (like 4) at the beginning of your line. Also, be sure that there is 2 carriage return. For, your answer, I said in my post I wanted to avoid your second possibility. For the first, I didn't want to resort to that solution, but maybe it's the only solution. I suppose creating my "array class" isn't too bad.

Comment: @SLaks: my uses call that kind of feature "bug" ;-)

Comment: @AngeDeLaMort: I didn't read well, sorry. I'm afraid those are the only extensibility points for the XmlSerializer. In any case, I meant to apply IXmlSerializable to the type containing the array, not to the array property.